# Can't read property of 'getHTML' of undefined Liferay CK Editor content

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am using C.K editor in my form, When I try to get the content in the CK editor I am getting **Can't read property of 'getHTML' of undefined**. the following is my code :
This is my html:

```
    <aui:layout>
        <aui:column columnWidth="100">
            <liferay-ui:input-editor width="100%" name='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()+"healthcontent" %>' height="550"  />
            <aui:input id="content" name="content" type="hidden" value='' />
            <div style="display: none;" id="<portlet:namespace/>healthcontentErrorDiv">
                <div class="portlet-msg-error">
                    Health Report content is required
                </div>
            </div>
        </aui:column>
    </aui:layout>
```

And below is my jquery code:

```
$jquery(".save-record").click(function(){
        try{
            alert('save record clicked');
            var flag = true;

            var title = $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>title").val();

            alert("title is "+title);

            if(title == null || title.trim() == ""){

                $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>titleErrorDiv").show();

                flag = false;
            }else{

                $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>titleErrorDiv").hide();

            }

        var health_content = window.<portlet:namespace/>healthcontent.getHTML();

        alert("health_content is "+health_content);

        if(health_content != null && health_content.trim() != ""){
            $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>content").val(health_content);
            $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>healthcontentErrorDiv").hide();
        }else{
            $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>healthcontentErrorDiv").show();
            flag = false;
        }

        // Submitting the form
        if(flag){
            $jquery("#<portlet:namespace/>HealthReportsAdministration").submit();   
        }
    }catch (e) {
        alert("Exception raised in HEALTH records11 "+e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified to

`<liferay-ui:input-editor width="100%" name="healthcontent" height="550"/>` I have also modified **inputCssClass** so i changed it to **cssClass**.

Answer (score 1):

window.healthcontent.getHTML(); is the culprit line. 
There is no such object present with the window object. Probably what you should do is, on place of following line

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor width="100%" name='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()+"healthcontent" %>' height="550"  />
```

Use

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor width="100%" name='<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()+"healthcontent" %>' id="<%= renderResponse.getNamespace()+"healthcontent" %>" height="550"  />
```

And then use

```
var health_content = $('#'+<portlet:namespace/>healthcontent);
```

Now do whatever you want on this variable.

Comment: May be you can use the autogenerated ID by the edditor. Also you can select using the name of the Editor